# TailwindCSS using selecting parent data attributes but styling children

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am wanting to make some components that are styled with TailwindCSS but I am attempting to use variants to select elements of a component.

Here is the basic component structure (Not visible to the end user). `{className}` is the className passed into the component.

```html
<div className={className}>
    <button>
        <span data-component="span">I need to be styled</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The end user will be able to use `MyComponent` and pass a class to target the sub span.

```html
<MyComponent className="ui-span:font-bold"/>
```

I want my user to be able to target the internal span styling from the parent. I was under the impression using a variant in a plugin could achieve this, but it is not working and I'm thinking this isn't the way `addVariant` is supposed to be used.

```js
addVariant('ui-span','&[data-component="span"]')
```

I'm not stuck on using data attributes, but the idea of being able to select interior components from the parent is the behaviour I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand that `&` means the element that the class is attached to. So given this:

```html
<div class="foo">
  <button>
    <span data-component="span">I need to be styled</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

`&[data-component="span"]` is equivalent to `.foo[data-component="span"]`.

However, we'd want `.foo [data-component="span"]` which can be derived from `& [data-component="span"]`:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <button>
      <span data-component="span">I need to be styled</span>
    </button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<MyComponent className="ui-span:text-red-500"/>);

tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('ui-span','& [data-component="span"]');
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```